# Download Windows 7 in "pieces"

Tags: windows-7, formatting

I am on very bad internet because I am traveling in New Zealand.

I need to download Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit (bootable) so that I can to a clean install on my Toshiba Laptop.

But I have tried several times now.. and the download usually crashes to several complications.

Wondering if there is a place where I can download the extracted ISO, that is to say, download the folders and files of the windows 7 installation seperately. So that I do not have to restart the Download each time it fails, but simply download the files I don't have yet.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a download manager (I use [Free download manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/))

It will allow you to continue a failed download, I don't have many issues with it and personally recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

It would be simpler to download the ISO with a software that allows resuming in case of problems.

Browsers such as Firefox and Opera support download resuming. Alternatively, you can install a download manager such as [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/index.htm) or [Internet Download Manager](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/) (a plug-in for most browsers).

The ISOs are freely available from the digitalriver website. You can find links to the ISOs of various Windows 7 editions [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/where-can-i-download-windows-7-iso-i-have-a/7d964b05-2be9-4800-bc7f-3ca30356fc3d), including Home Premium x64.